# Стилизация label на GoogleMap

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Как стилизовать label на googlemap?

На данный момент есть такой код:

```
for (var i = 0; i < item_office_length; i++) {
    var beach = item_office[i];
    var labelPointer =  (i + 1) + "";
    var icon = "/images/marker_1.png";

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: beach[1], lng: beach[2]},
        icon: icon,
        map: map,
        label: labelPointer,
        labelClass: "label_pointer_style",
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
        labelStyle: {color: "red"}

    });
}
```

Маркеры и лэйблы выводяться, но стилизовать не получается.

Comment: думаю, вам [сюда](https://habrahabr.ru/post/131654/)

Comment: К сожалению в данной статье нет описания, для изменения стилей лейблов